# Encoding audio data using ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am receiving a byte array (`int8_t*`) and I would like to use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) to encode it into FLAC. All the examples I found are reading data from files, which is not the case for me. Following the original documents (see [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding-example_8c-source.html)), I came up with the following solution:

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"

// ...

// params:
//  audioData: original audio data
//  len: length of the byte array (audio data)
//  sampleRate: sample rate of the original audio data
//  frameSize: frame size of the original data
uint8_t* encodeToFlac(uint8_t* audioData, int len, int sampleRate, int frameSize) {
  uint8_t* convertedAudioData;

  // Context information
  AVCodecContext* context = avcodec_alloc_context();
  context->bit_rate = 64000;
  context->sample_rate = sampleRate;
  context->channels = 2;
  context->frame_size = frameSize;

  short* samples = malloc(frameSize * 2 * context->channels);
  int outAudioDataSize = len * 2;
  convertedAudioData = malloc(outAudioDataSize);
  int outSize = avcodec_encode_audio(c, convertedAudioData, outAudioDataSize, samples);

  return convertedAudioData;
}
```

I have two main issues with the above solution:

1. I did not specify what the final encoding should be (for example, MP3, FLAC, etc), which makes me wonder if I'm using FFMPEG library correctly?
2. Do I have all the necessary information about the source - original audio data? I am not certain if I have all the necessary information to perform the encoding.

Comment: It would be way easier to just use libflac directly.

Comment: It's not a part of ffmpeg, is it? I'm afraid I do not have anything other than ffmpeg to use.

Comment: `I'm afraid I do not have anything other than ffmpeg to use` You can download it.

Comment: Yes, but not for this project, I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there, follow this example: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_audio.c

Answer to 1st question:
There you'll see `codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP2)`.
In your case, you guessed it, it probably will be `codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_FLAC)` and check/fix other values accordingly.

As for 2nd one... I'm sure you'll find out yourself, especially you must set this correctly (line 158) `c->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` according to what your `int8_t` array formatted.

Hope that helps.